# Returning all the values in the array

Tags: arrays, matlab

For the following function in `matlab`:

```
function s = support(x, y)
for i=1:length(x)
if(y(i)~=1)
s = x(i);
end
end
end
```

I was intending to return **all** the values that meet the `if-statement`, but seems that the function only returns the **last** element that satisfies the `if-statement. How can I return all the values? What modification should I apply?

Comment: The main problem is that `s` gets overwritten at each iteration of the loop (also: an `end` is missing).

Comment: @WhoeverDownvotedThis: What is wrong in asking a basic question?

Comment: @Jonas. I included the `end`s. Thanks for your note...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write

```
s = x(y~=1)
```

This will return all elements in `x` that satisfy your condition (`y~=1`). However, if `s` should be the same size as `x` and `y`, then it may make more sense to mask the elements in `s` where the condition is false, i.e.

```
s = x;
s(y==1) = NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Your s value is not an array so you return only the last value

```
function s = support(x, y)
j=1;
for i=1:length(x)
  if(y(i)~=1)
    s(j) = x(i);
    j=j+1;
  end
end
```

Note also that for this kind of problem there is a lot of syntax shorcuts in Matlab which are very more efficient and this is the power of Matlab. You could just write:

```
function s = support(x, y)
s=x(y~=1);
```

(Look at logical indexing to understand)

Answer (score 0):

use logical indexing to return all elements in `x` that satisfy the condition `y not 1`:

```
s = x( y ~= 1)
```